# condition to show f is integrable with respect to a measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathbb{X},\mu)$ be a measure space with $f_n$ on $X$ defined by

$   f_n(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f(x) & |f(x)| \leq n\\
       n & f(x)>n \\
      -n &  f(x)<-n\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Prove if

$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int |f_n| d\mu<\infty$ then f is integrable.

I've been having a hard time proving the above, and I'm actually not sure if the statement of the proof needs this specific definition of $f_n$ or not. I'm just not sure how I can use the properties of sup to show that f is integrable in this sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we only have to prove that $\int \vert f\vert d\mu<\infty$ because $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. Now, by its definition, we have that 
$$
|f_n|(x)= \left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
|f(x)| & |f(x)|\leq n\\
n & |f(x)|>n
\end{array}
\right .
$$

Ans therefore,  $|f_n| \to |f|$ point wise as $n\to \infty$ and also we have that $|f_n|\leq |f_{n+1}|$ for every positive integer $n$. Then, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem we have
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n| d\mu= \int |f| d\mu
$$
But the sequence $\{\int |f_n|d\mu\}$ is an increasing sequence, so it follows that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n| d\mu= \sup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int |f_n| d\mu
$$
Hence,
$$
\int |f| d\mu= \sup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int |f_n| d\mu<\infty
$$
Then, $|f|$ is integrable as we wanted to show.